# Two TMemo objects sharing one TPopupMenu

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a `TForm` with two `TMemo` objects and one `TPopupMenu`. Both `TMemo`s are using the same `TPopupMenu`.

The popup menu has one item for 'clearing' the Memo, through the use of a `TAction`.

My question is, when clicking on the Menu item on one of the `TMemo`s, how can I figure out which `TMemo` was the one that displayed the `TPopupMenu`?

I have the following code in the `TAction`'s execute function:

```
TAction* action = dynamic_cast<TAction*>(Sender);

TMenuItem* item = dynamic_cast<TMenuItem*>(action->ActionComponent);
if(item)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<TMemo*>(item->Owner))
    {
        dynamic_cast<TMemo*>(item->Owner) -> Clear();
    }
}
```

But the `TMenuItem`'s owner is not a `TMemo`.

Any hints? I hope to avoid to have to use two different `TPopupMenu`s.

Comment: `TPopupMenu.PopupComponent` should help.  `Owner` isn't helpful at all, as it just tells you what is responsible for freeing the menu itself, and is going to be the form it was dropped on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `TPopupMenu::PopupComponent` property to know which `TMemo` invoked the menu:

```
TMemo *memo = dynamic_cast<TMemo*>(PopupMenu1->PopupComponent);
if (memo)
    memo->Clear();
```

Or, if you want to discover the `TPopupMenu` that the `TMenuItem` is linked to:

```
TAction* action = static_cast<TAction*>(Sender);

TMenuItem* item = dynamic_cast<TMenuItem*>(action->ActionComponent);
if (item)
{
    TPopupMenu *popup = dynamic_cast<TPopupMenu*>(item->GetParentMenu());
    if (popup)
    {
        TMemo *memo = dynamic_cast<TMemo*>(popup->PopupComponent);
        if (memo)
            memo->Clear();
    }
}
```